# cannot create directory `/nonexistent/.meteor-install-tmp'

Tags: nginx, meteor, passenger

Following meteor passenger tutorial here: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Meteor-tutorial#deploying_to_production. Using meteor 1.0.2.1 and passenger 4.0.57.
The public and tmp directory both exist.

But got the error

```
App 10979 stderr: mkdir: 
App 10979 stderr: cannot create directory `/nonexistent/.meteor-install-tmp'
App 10979 stderr: : No such file or directory
```

when starting the server. Can't figure out where went wrong.

The nginx config was:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /root/myapp/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_sticky_sessions on;
    passenger_set_cgi_param MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor;
    passenger_set_cgi_param MONGO_OPLOG_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/local;
    passenger_set_cgi_param ROOT_URL http://www.example.com;

    # Set these ONLY if your app is a Meteor bundle!
    #passenger_app_type node;
    #passenger_startup_file main.js;
}
```

Comment: getting the same error with apache after 4 years.. Could you find a way?

Comment: I changed to deploy Meteor as bundle and didn't get this bug